# popToRootViewController and how to update info at here

Tags: iphone, ios

**Scenario**

The structure that I am having for my project is

```
A---B---C---D---E
```

A is the root view and I am in E

After doing some transactions successfully, I am doing

```
- (void) successfulToDoTransaction: {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This will take me back at A controller and in A I would like to display some info that has been done successfully in E.

**Goal :**

What is the best way to tell view controller A reload so that it can get the latest info... I am thinking about using notification like below (pseudo code ) but not so sure this is the best way to do that...

Please advice if you have any ideas about this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always add in your -(void)viewDidAppear method to reload content.  If that's not the route you want to take then use an NSNotificationCenter and addObserver in view controller A and postNotification in view controller E.

Comment: I did try with viewWillAppear and put breakpoint at this method but it did not hit. That is why I switch to nsnotification. I forgot viewDidAppear method. thanks to remind me.

Answer (score 2):

Make your root view controller 'A' a **delegate** of 'E'

You can pass 'A' by making it a property of your intermediate view controllers.

For a good example of delegation check out Apple's Recipe sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html